# Two negative binomial models, 1 with & 1 without correlations between random slopes & intercepts: no change in resulting estimates! Why?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme, negative-binomial-distribution

**Short Version**

I have two mixed effect models which are exactly the same, except one includes all correlations between random slopes and between random slopes and intercepts, while the other includes no such correlations. The resulting estimates, standard errors, and p-values for both models are very, very nearly identical... Why?

**More details**

- The `Response` is count data and is zero-inflated
- Fit using `lme4::glmer.nb` (negative binomial distribution) in R
- includes the offset of observation time, `Hours`
- Optimizing using bobyqa: `glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=1000000), optimizer = "bobyqa")`
- The model formulas are ...

`full_model = Response ~ A + B + C + offset(log(Hours)) + (1 + A + B | RandomEffect)`

`reduced_model = Response ~ A + B + C + offset(log(Hours)) + (1 + A + B  || RandomEffect)`

where `A`, and `B` are continuous and `C` is a factor with two levels.

- `anova(reduced_model, full_model, test="Chisq")` gives `Chisq=0`, `Pr(>Chisq)=1`
- values of estimates vary *a little* but are identical to 5 decimal places. In other words, `round( summary(full_model)$coefficients, 5) == round(summary(reduced_model)$coefficients, 5)`
  is `TRUE` for all values of `Estimate`, `Std. Error`, `z value`, and `Pr(>|z|)`

**Wouldn't one expect more variation in estimates from models with and without correlations between random slopes and intercepts? What does it mean that there is so little change in the estimates generated by these two models?**

Comment: Some plots of the data along with the fitted lines might help with a diagnosis.

Comment: Maybe the intercepts and slopes are close to 0? Could you post the summary of both models?

Comment: What I meant to say was: Maybe the correlations between the intercepts and slopes are close to 0. That would make both models very similar